# Python: logging comments printed to console before other outputs

Tags: python, logging

I have been trying to understand logging in python. I have an **init** module, two other modules and a main module. For some reason, when I run my module, log details jump the code flow and are printed first before the other outputs

Could someone tell me why this is happening

this is in `__init__.py`

```
from dir1.mod1 import FirstClass
from dir1.mod2 import SecondClass

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler=logging.FileHandler('python_logs.log')
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
c_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

f_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
c_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

f_handler.setFormatter(f_formatter)
c_handler.setFormatter(c_formatter)

logger.addHandler(f_handler)
logger.addHandler(c_handler)
```

This is in other two modules(written inside `__init__()` of the resp class

```
self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

snippet of addn() function defined inside one of the module

```
def addn(self):
    z=self.x +self.y
    print('sum is '+z)
    self.logger.error('incrementing number!')
    self.logger.info('Still incrementing number!!')
    return z
```

And my main modules(which I run) has this:

```
from dir1.mod1 import FirstClass
from dir1.mod2 import SecondClass

number = FirstClass(2,2)
print('addition results')
number.addn()
```

**I was expecting a output as below**

addition results

sum is 3

`dir1.mod1` - ERROR - incrementing number!

**But what I got was**

`dir1.mod1` - ERROR - incrementing number!

`dir1.mod1` - ERROR - incrementing number!

addition results:

sum is 3

Why is the log message printed first jumping out of code flow? And also could someone tell me why log message gets printed twice??

Comment: In your `addn` function, you're mixing `print` and logging. What happens if you replace `print` with `self.logger.info` ? I suspect flushing of print and logger doesn't occur in the order you imagine.

Comment: In that case, 'addition results' should ideally be printed first because it gets executed before addn function is called right?... but I am still getting addition results after log messages

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python StreamHandler will log to stderr by default while you print statements goes to stdout. Those are two different pipelines and the ordering isn't guaranteed between them.

To ensure proper ordering start by sending all output to the same pipe. For example you could add the `file=sys.stderr` argument to your print statements.

Comment: Thanks that worked!. But I am still unsure on why the logs are printing two times

Comment: This does solve the jumping behavior. But `print` might be called far more often than a globally initialized `logger`. Maybe it's easier to configure `logger` instead of having to add `file=sys.stderr` each time one calls `print`?

Comment: Yes I'm not sanctioning this code in any way. Actually you don't need a global logger, you just need to import and instantiate the logger in your module; if I'm not mistaken the logging class will apply the logging configuration across the board.

Answer (score 4):

U can try disable the propagate property of your logger.

> **Propagate**: If this attribute evaluates to true, events logged to this logger will be passed to the handlers of higher level (ancestor) loggers, in addition to any handlers attached to this logger. Messages are passed directly to the ancestor loggers’ handlers - neither the level nor filters of the ancestor loggers in question are considered.

This is an example of init logger that uses file and stdout with different debug level:

```
def init_logger_singleton():

    global logger

    logger = logging.getLogger(name='loggerName')
    logger.propagate = False
    logger.setLevel(10)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '\t%(message)s'
    )

    filehandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    filehandler.setLevel(40)
    filehandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(filehandler)
```

I used number to define the log level, but 10 = DEBUG and 40 = ERRO. More information at [this link.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels)

Answer (score 2):

U can also add argument `sys.stdout` to your stream handler, so both `print` and logger events will be passing to one channel.

```
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
```